# Stochastic Integral of the exponential of a process to it self

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

This is probably very easy, but i couldn't solve it so far.

Let $Y_{t}=\alpha dW_{t}$ for a constant $\alpha \in\mathbb{R}$ and a Brownian Motion $W$. Is the local Martingale $e^{Y_t}dY_t$ a true martingale ?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I tried to show that that the Integrand is sufficiently integrable. So if I could show $\mathbb{E} [ \int_{0}^{t} (e^{Y_s} )^2 ds]<\infty $, then I would be done. But I don’t know how to do this or if it is even true.

Comment: Can you compute $\mathbb{E}[(e^{Y_s})^2]$?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[(e^{Y_t})^2]=\mathbb{E}[(e^{2\alpha dW_t})]=\mathbb{E}[(e^{2\alpha dW_t-2\alpha^2dt+2\alpha^2 dt})]=e^{2\alpha dt}\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{E}(2\alpha dW_s)(t)]\leq e^{2\alpha dt}\mathbb{E}[\mathcal{E}(2\alpha dW_s)(0)]= e^{2\alpha dt} $  since the stochastic exponential $\mathcal{E}(2\alpha dW_s)(t)$ is a supermartingale. Is this correct ?

Comment: @ez43eg It would normally be written without the differential, i.e. as $\mathcal{E}(2\alpha W)(t)$ instead of $\mathcal{E}(2\alpha dW_s)(t)$, but yes, that is correct.  Now how can you use that to show $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t (e^{Y_s})^2ds]<\infty$?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[\int_{0}^{t}(e^{Y_s})^2ds]=\int_{0}^t\mathbb{E}[(e^{Y_s})^2 ] ds\leq \int_0^t e^{2\alpha s} ds<\infty$ by using Tonellis Theorem.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  I summarized this discussion as an answer so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, to show $\int_0^t e^{Y_s}dY_s$ is a true martingale, it is sufficient to show $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t (e^{Y_s})^2 ds] < \infty$.  We compute

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[(e^{Y_s})^2] &= \mathbb{E}[e^{2 \alpha W_s}] \\
&= e^{2 \alpha^2 t}
\end{align*}
by using the known expression for the moment generating function of a $N(0,s)$ random variable.  Thus, by Tonelli's theorem,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t (e^{Y_s})^2 ds] &= \int_0^t \mathbb{E}[(e^{Y_s})^2] ds \\
&= \int_0^t e^{2 \alpha^2 s} ds <\infty,
\end{align*}
so we conclude $\int_0^t e^{Y_s}dY_s$ is in fact a true martingale.